# Javap equivalent utility for DotNet

Tags: java, .net

As we know in java,  `javap` (java parser) utility shows all the method names in a Class.

**Is there any equivalent utility for Dot-Net ?**

Answer (score 0):

You must use Reflection. Try this code:

```
var methodNames = your_object
    .GetType()
    .GetMethods()
    .Select(m => m.Name)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: ok..But i was searching for a command line utility like javap. Is there any ?